# sql query in exact match

Tags: sql

let's say I have the following table

```
name | color
-------------
jon    blue
jon    black
jon    red
bill   blue
bill   red
jack   blue
....
```

I'd like to run a query to get all names with only colors = blue and red
and same thing for a qeyry with all names where color = blue only (no black, no red)

I've tried something like below

```
select name, color from table where color in ('blue', 'red')
group by name, color
```

but it gives me more results than I expect...
Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: `select name, color from table where color in ('blue', 'red') AND random() < 0.5
group by name, color` will give you less. The Spanish inquisition!

Answer (score 0):

```
  select name
    from tbl
   where color in ('blue','red')
     and not exists (select * from tbl t2
                     where t2.name=tbl.name and t2.color NOT IN ('blue','red'))
group by name
  having count(distinct color) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try this query:

```
SELECT name, color
FROM table1
WHERE name IN
(
    SELECT name
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE color IN ('blue', 'red')
      AND NOT EXISTS
      (
         SELECT * 
         FROM table1 t2 
         WHERE t1.name = t2.name
           AND t2.color NOT IN ('blue', 'red')
       )
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color) = 2 --to be sure only red won't be accepted

    UNION

    SELECT name
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE color = 'blue'
     AND NOT EXISTS
     (
        SELECT * 
        FROM table1 t2 
        WHERE t1.name = t2.name
          AND t2.color <> 'blue'
     )
)
ORDER BY name, color
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Really have to think changing the structure of that table. too big of a query for a simple search.

Comment: Yep, I agree with you if the query to be called time and time. :(